# Converting a pandas dataframe into year from datetime

Tags: python, datetime

```
df['Feedback Year']= df['Feedback Date'].strftime("%B")
```

**The error:**

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Comment: should be `df['Feedback Date'].dt.strftime("%B")`

Comment: if `df['Feedback Year']` is not of `dtype` `datetime`, you will have to convert it first before you can use methods of that class like `.dt.strftime("%B")`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['Feedback Year']= df['Feedback Date'].dt.strftime("%B")
```

Or

```
df['Feedback Year']= df['Feedback Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%B'))
```